# Pyspark: how to extract hour from timestamp

Tags: python, sql, pyspark

I have a table like the following

```
    df

 +------------------------------------+-----------------------+
|identifier                          |timestamp              |
+------------------------------------+-----------------------+
|86311425-0890-40a5-8950-54cbaaa60815|2020-03-18 14:41:55 UTC|
|38e121a8-f21f-4d10-bb69-26eb045175b5|2020-03-13 15:19:21 UTC|
|1a69c9b0-283b-4b6d-89ac-66f987280c66|2020-03-16 12:59:51 UTC|
|c7b5c53f-bf40-498f-8302-4b3329322bc9|2020-03-18 22:05:06 UTC|
|0d3d807b-9b3a-466e-907c-c22402240730|2020-03-17 18:40:03 UTC|
+------------------------------------+-----------------------+

tmp.printSchema()
root
 |-- identifier: string (nullable = true)
 |-- timestamp: string (nullable = true)
```

I would like to have a column that take only the day and the hours from the timestamp.

I am trying the following:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import hour
df = df.withColumn("hour", hour(col("timestamp")))
```

but I get the following

```
+--------------------+--------------------+----+
|          identifier|           timestamp|hour|
+--------------------+--------------------+----+
|321869c3-71e5-41d...|2020-03-19 03:34:...|null|
|226b8d50-2c6a-471...|2020-03-19 02:59:...|null|
|47818b7c-34b5-43c...|2020-03-19 01:41:...|null|
|f5ca5599-7252-49d...|2020-03-19 04:25:...|null|
|add2ae24-aa7b-4d3...|2020-03-19 01:50:...|null|
+--------------------+--------------------+----+
```

while I would like to have

```
+--------------------+--------------------+-------------------+
|          identifier|           timestamp|hour               |
+--------------------+--------------------+-------------------+
|321869c3-71e5-41d...|2020-03-19 03:00:...|2020-03-19 03:00:00|
|226b8d50-2c6a-471...|2020-03-19 02:59:...|2020-03-19 02:00:00|
|47818b7c-34b5-43c...|2020-03-19 01:41:...|2020-03-19 01:00:00|
|f5ca5599-7252-49d...|2020-03-19 04:25:...|2020-03-19 04:00:00|
|add2ae24-aa7b-4d3...|2020-03-19 01:50:...|2020-03-19 01:00:00|
+--------------------+--------------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: [Edit] the question to include the schema (`df.printSchema()`) and show the dataframe with `truncate=False`.

Comment: Also specify what output you're expecting

Comment: @pault just modified the answer

Answer (score 14):

You should use pyspark inbuilt function `date_trunc` to truncate to `hour`. You can also truncate to day/month/year etc.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df.withColumn("hour", F.date_trunc('hour',F.to_timestamp("timestamp","yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss 'UTC'")))\
  .show(truncate=False)


+------------------------------------+-----------------------+-------------------+
|identifier                          |timestamp              |hour               |
+------------------------------------+-----------------------+-------------------+
|86311425-0890-40a5-8950-54cbaaa60815|2020-03-18 14:41:55 UTC|2020-03-18 14:00:00|
|38e121a8-f21f-4d10-bb69-26eb045175b5|2020-03-13 15:19:21 UTC|2020-03-13 15:00:00|
|1a69c9b0-283b-4b6d-89ac-66f987280c66|2020-03-16 12:59:51 UTC|2020-03-16 12:00:00|
|c7b5c53f-bf40-498f-8302-4b3329322bc9|2020-03-18 22:05:06 UTC|2020-03-18 22:00:00|
|0d3d807b-9b3a-466e-907c-c22402240730|2020-03-17 18:40:03 UTC|2020-03-17 18:00:00|
+------------------------------------+-----------------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: How would you get the actual hour number?

Comment: @RaminMelikov F.hour

Comment: Can I get the scala version of this please?

Answer (score 6):

You asked to get both date and hour, you can use the function provided by pyspark to extract only the date and hour like below:

3 steps:

- Transform the timestamp column to timestamp format
- Use date function to extract the date from the timestamp format
- Use hour function to extract the hour from the timestamp format

The code would look like this:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
# Step 1: transform to the correct col format
df = df.withColumn("timestamp", to_timestamp("timestamp", 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'))

# Step 2 & 3: Extract the needed information
df = df.withColumn('Date', date(df.timestamp))
df = df.withColumn('Hour', hour(df.timestamp))

# Display the result
df.show(1, False)
#+----------+--------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
#|identifier|           timestamp|               Date|               Hour|
#+----------+--------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
#|         1|2020-03-19 03:00:...|                 19|                 03|
#+----------+--------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
```

The hour col does not look exactly like what you describe since it's already been answered by notNull above. This is another way if you only want to get the number of date and hour for later groupby or aggregation for example.

Comment: The 'date' function doesn't exist in this form within pyspark currently. To achieve the above result 'dayofmonth' needs to be used

Answer (score 3):

Use `from_unixtime and unix_timestamp`functions as `hour` is used to extract hour value from `timestamp` (or) `string(yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss)` type

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
#sample data
df.show(truncate=False)
#+----------+-----------------------+
#|identifier|timestamp              |
#+----------+-----------------------+
#|1         |2020-03-18 14:41:55 UTC|
#+----------+-----------------------+
#DataFrame[identifier: string, timestamp: string]

df.withColumn("hour", from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(col("timestamp"),"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"),"yyyy-MM-dd hh:00:00")).show()
#+----------+--------------------+-------------------+
#|identifier|           timestamp|               hour|
#+----------+--------------------+-------------------+
#|         1|2020-03-18 14:41:...|2020-03-18 14:00:00|
#+----------+--------------------+-------------------+
```

---

**`Usage of hour function:`**

```
#on string type 
spark.sql("select hour('2020-03-04 12:34:34')").show()
#on timestamp type
spark.sql("select hour(timestamp('2020-03-04 12:34:34'))").show()
#+---+
#|_c0|
#+---+
#| 12|
#+---+
```

Answer (score 3):

why not just a custom udf?

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType

hour = F.udf(lambda x: x.hour, IntegerType())
hours = df.withColumn("hour", hour("datetime"))

hours.limit(5).toPandas()
```

will give you this:

[image]

Comment: because using a custom udf is more expensive than using inbuilt pyspark functions

Answer (score 2):

For Spark 3.3.0, a simple `hour` and `weekofyear` does the magic. Assumption: `timestamp` is already in correct format

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as SF

(
  df
  .withColumn("hour"      , SF.hour("timestamp") )
  .withColumn("weekofyear", SF.weekofyear("timestamp") )
  .show(n=2)
)
```